# Is the water absorbed by sodium polyacrylate available to react?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reactivity, absorption

I'm curious whether the water absorbed by sodium polyacrylate would react with alkali metals, or be trapped by the sodium polyacrylate.

Comment: "React" in what way? Absorbing water is also a reaction, it just depends on who wants it *more*.

Comment: This is too broad. In hydrate of CuSO4 water is covalently bound, in super-absorbent it's just hydrogen bonds.